# SQL server 2012 - group by month, 3 month, 6 months, 11 months and prior year 11 months

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2012, summary, categorization

Trying to build a query to have sum on sales column by month, 3 months, 6 months, 11 months and prior year 11 months. What are possible options to go about it. 
I tried datediff and date related functions didn't get intended results.

Would like some suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: Are you trying to build some sort of pivot table?

Comment: Or a running totals calculation? Please give examples.

Comment: yes, CM, C3M, C6M, PY11M as pivot columns eventually. However, I can get pivot through other analytical tools, but grouping is troubing more.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Basically group by Product category, Channel and then current year month, current year 3 months, current year 6 months, current year 12 months and then prior year 12 months.

Comment: Are the groupings mutually exclusive?  so 1 month isn't in 3 months or is the 3 months including the 1 month?  And are you expecting this to be in 1 column (So a Group by Grouping sets? multiple rows for each range) or 1 column for each month range?  (Sample data and expected results always a plus!)

Comment: Nope, they can be inclusive. 1 column for each month range. Sorry having trouble with formating...please find Gsheet for review - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g9P8y-6p5H3MUbg3Trkqg6zHkEnoGMriD2vwRilIFdI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    product varchar (1),
    month int,
    amount int
)
insert into sales values ('a',1,5); insert into sales values ('a',1,33); 
insert into sales values ('a',2,32); insert into sales values ('b',1,12); 
insert into sales values ('b',2,4); insert into sales values ('c',1,5);
insert into sales values ('c',2,11);  insert into sales values ('c',2,13);

SELECT 
    product,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN amount END) AS Month1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 2 THEN amount END) AS Month2
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    product

output:

product   | Month1   |  Month2   
--------------------------------
    a     |   38     |   32   
    b     |   12     |   4
    c     |   5      |   24
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking for date ranges - Currentyear-currentmonth, currentyear-3months, currentyear-6months, currentyear-9months, currentyear-12months, prioryear-12months etc.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work using DATEDIFF function...will post once I complete the query.

Comment: awesome. all the best